# How to sync ticks(Frames) between two peers?

Tags: frame-rate, synchronization

I have a peer to peer game where both clients are running their own frame simulation. I'd like to sync the frame ticks so both peers know eachother's frame. But I"m having a bit of issue with this and I can't figure out why it's so hard to sync the frame tick.

What I attempted was,

Host begins game

Peer joins the game and lets the host know they joined

The host sends a packet

Peer receives the packet and makes a note of its own tick

Host sends another packet one frame later

Peer receives this packet and subtracts the earlier tick from its current to get the one way distance in ticks

Now the peer can assign their own frame tick to the host's and add the travel time to it so they should technically now be sync'd

But for some reason this doesn't work.. they're always off by 2 or 3 ticks and I can't figure out why

Comment: By the time you receive a packet from the server, it's already out of date. So you'd need to back-date the time of receipt back to the moment/tick that corresponds with when it was *sent*. [There's some discussion in this article about estimating round-trip time](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/reliability_ordering_and_congestion_avoidance_over_udp/) to get the right correction factor.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for the response. I understand the first packet received from the server is out of date, but if the server sends another packet 1 frame later, can the client not use that as a measurement of one way trip time from server to client?

Comment: Trip time varies, so usually you want to average it across multiple recent replies. The measurement also has to be between query sent and reply receipt, not between reply and second reply, otherwise the bulk of what you're measuring is not the communication latency but the server-side tick frequency, plus a noise term.

Comment: Hmm okay, let me change up my design a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your description correctly, your timeline of events during a join looks something like this...

[image: Timeline diagram]

Some things to notice here:

- The time it takes an update to travel across the network from server to client is not always the same - there's some variance due to congestion, buffering, etc.
- The time between receiving your first and second messages from the server is not a good measure of one-way trip latency. What you're measuring is the sum of...

  - the time elapsed on the server between the two messages being sent (either one frame/tick if the join message is processed as part of the tick, or one tick plus some loose change that's just up to the happenstance of when between ticks your message was processed)
  - plus the *difference* in latency between the two messages. So if the first message took longer than usual to reach you and the second took less time than usual, you'll get a smaller result. If the first message arrived quickly and the second was slower, you'll get a larger result. Neither tells you anything about the typical latency.

This is effectively just noise in terms of what you really want to measure, which is "how far into the past should I back-date newly-received server messages?"

To estimate that, you need to do a combination of things:

- Measure from the time the client sent a message to the time it received an acknowledgement. This gives you round-trip time, from which you can estimate one-way latency by dividing by two.
- Send acknowledgements immediately, not deferred until the next tick - otherwise you're adding an unknown amount of loose change into the estimate. (If you need to batch up replies, you can track how long the server held a message before replying, and send that delay number as part of the payload, so the client can subtract it out again)
- Do several rounds of this and filter the results. Any single round trip may be plagued by errors or outliers, but taking the median of several round trips will get you a better estimate of the real trend.

This may mean you spend several ticks "handshaking" before you have enough confidence in the time disparity to join the simulation at the right offset, but this can often happen in parallel/in the background while loading the level, displaying the lobby or join message, or other pre-gameplay fanfare.

Comment: Thanks DMGregory! What I ended up doing was follow a similar model to what you had told me. When client joins, send packet instantly. When server receives it, respond immediately with its frame. Client receives the frame and responds immediately with ACK, server recieves it and responds immedately again with the round trip time. Now the client knows the round trip and the last frame the server was on. Then it's just a calculation of server frame+ round trip time/2. And yes this is done during a "Sync" phase not actual gameplay. Once sync'd the game can begin.

Comment: That sounds like an average of two round trips, which will be more robust than measuring just one, but still susceptible to significant skews if either the first or second message gets unlucky.

Comment: So after the first ACK from the client you recommend repeated ACK between the server and the client to get one way trip times?

Comment: And I should use median instead of average? I think if I send 5 ACK's back and forth and take the median of that, it should be a lot more accurate yes?

Comment: That's what the answer says, yes. It will be less vulnerable to skewing from outliers. Also, you generally measure on the client side, from the time the client sent a message to the time the client received the server ack, so the server doesn't have to calculate and send the RTT in its message.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much! I'm finally beginning to understand game networking!

Comment: I'm also wondering if it's okay for the frames to be off by 1 or two during round trip calculation. Most of the time it will calculate round trip time correctly but not so often it will be off by 1. If this happens should I attempt to resync until they're perfectly aligned?

Comment: You'll never know what perfectly aligned is, sadly. All you can do is appropriate to within a tolerance that works for your gameplay.